# Getting compass to generate a border-radius that works in ie8

Tags: sass, css3pie, compass-sass

I'm very new to Compass and SASS (just getting beyond a very basic understanding, to the testbed stage), and would like to try creating a div with border-radius characteristics that will work cross-browser, including in IE8.
I have successfully installed SASS and Compass, and this has created a standard files structure with ie.scss and screen.scss. The Compass watch command works ok and successfully compiles the SASS commands. However I can't seem to get the border-radius to work in IE8 (using PIE).

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/support";
@import "compass/css3/pie";
$legacy-support-for-ie: true;
.compound { @include border-radius(10px 15px, 10px 16px);
            border: 1px solid;
            behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

I've tried putting this in both screen.scss and ie.scss apparently to no effect. I must be missing something... but what?

Here is the HTML by the way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/pie.css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- [if IE]>
            <link href="stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Test de compass</h1></div>
        <div class="compound">
            <p>Suspendisse bibendum libero eu tortor tempor, non convallis lectus hendrerit. 
</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that you're using PIE correctly?

Comment: Well, that is precisely my problem: I presume that I am not using PIE correctly, but I cannot work out what is incorrect in what I have done!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - maybe this will help others.

I was running on a test bed installed under Wampserver, so the address of the test site's home page was `http://localhost/pietest/index.html`
However, when you install PIE it assumes that you are at the web server root, so the URL created in the pie.scss file generated at installation was incorrect. It was using the absolute address of the web server ("/stylesheets/pie.HTC"), whereas it needed to be a relative address: this worked - "stylesheets/pie.HTC"